# open google maps to bus directions

Tags: iphone, google-maps

I realise that you can open the google maps app ready for directions by doing something like this:

```
NSString* urlString = @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=London+UK&daddr=Birmingham+UK";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlString]];
```

But is there a parameter I can add to automatically switch to bus directions? Apple's developer document doesn't seem to mention anything about it:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [MapKiWiki](http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters#Directions):

dirflg Route type:

- dirflg=h - Switches on "Avoid Highways"
  route finding mode.
- dirflg=t - Switches on "Avoid Tolls"
  route finding mode.
- dirflg=r - Switches on "Public Transit" - only works in some areas.
- dirflg=w - Switches to walking
  directions - still in beta.
- dirflg=d - Switches to driving
  directions.

So your URL:

```
NSString* urlString = @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=London+UK&daddr=Birmingham+UK";
```

Becomes:

```
NSString* urlString = @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=London+UK&daddr=Birmingham+UK&dirflg=r";
```

N.B. The data supporting public transit route types are not always available.  I tried the area you used in your sample (London, Birmingham) and found it was not supported.

Comment: How can we see this page in XML format now? Such as the driving directions given in XML format. For example: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=111%20Davisville%20Avenue,Toronto,ON&destination=469%20King%20Street%20West,%20Toronto,%20ON&sensor=false&dirflg=r even though there is dirflg=r at the end, it still shows driving directions.

Comment: the link is dead :-/

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr="+latitude+","+longitude+"&dirflg=r";
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)); 
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

`dirflg=r` is for public transport.