# Is there an Android equivalent to Google Maps URL scheme for iOS?

Tags: android, mobile-website

I want to open Google Maps in Navigation mode from a mobile web link. This seems easy enough for iOS devices using https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme

Is there an equivalent for Android? All I could find was this: https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html

But that doesn't allow you to specify "transitmode" and the other parameters needed to get directions as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, a slight modification of the methods described in the iOS Doc would work here too (I tested it before putting it here albeit, in a native app and not a web link).

The parameters necessary for this to work are pretty much the same as with the ones listed in the iOS documentation:

[From the iOS Docs:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme#directions)

**Parameters:**

- **saddr**: Sets the starting point for directions searches. This can be a
  latitude,longitude or a query formatted address. If it is a query
  string that returns more than one result, the first result will be
  selected. If the value is left blank, then the user’s current
  location will be used.
- **daddr**: Sets the end point for directions    searches. Has the same
  format and behavior as saddr.
- **directionsmode**:    Method of    transportation. Can be set to:
  driving, transit, or walking.

They are actually, pretty much the same. They are however, no where to be found in the documents. Also, while the first 2 parameters work the usual way here, the last parameter ***directionsmode*** does not work as is. A workaround is however, listed below.

That being said, a simple URL can be constructed that can then be passed as an `Uri` to an `Intent` that will then handle the application to be launched (Google Maps if installed and/or list of browsers to choose from)

```
String mapURL = http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=-33.9417, 150.9473&daddr=-33.92050, 151.04287&dirflg=d
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(mapURL));
startActivity(intent);
```

A few variations for the *Transit Mode*:

1. *&dirflg=d* = for `Driving` directions (this is the default mode. leaving it out is the same as putting it in explicityly).
2. *&dirflg=w* = for Walking directions
3. *&dirflg=r* = for Public transit.
4. *&dirflg=b* = for Biking directions.

That being said, at the time of running these test (*I admit I was curious enough to test a little further after seeing this question* ;-) ), the modes listed in [the Travel Modes section](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#TravelModes) **don't** seem work!

**A little proof of sorts:**

[image]
[image]

Note: [Credit for the initial discovery of the options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1057648/450534)