# Google Maps show multiple locations

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I want to show with google maps multiple locations

To show one i would go to
https://www.maps.google.com/maps?daddr=20.5666,45.345

What if I want to go to something like this
[image]

Something like

https://www.maps.google.com/maps?daddr=20.5666,45.345 &daddr=23.5666,45.345 &daddr=22.5666,45.345  .

Is that possible from the url?

Answer (score 0):

If you can redirect user to the Google Maps app, I would recommend the solution described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17916883/963881).

If not, you can simply parse the locations from you URL, convert them to `GeoPoint`s and show the on a map.

Comment: Using that url you can only use 2 locations.